# React props tipo registro con array

Tags: array, reactjs, props

tengo un componente funcional (SelectTable) al que le paso una props de este tipo:

```
user{
    numeroEmpleado: string,
    nif: string,
    status: bool,
    employees: []
}

<SelectTable
    user= this.state.user
/>
```

Cuando intento acceder al array employees desde el componente me dice que está indefinido:

```
const SelectTable = (props) =>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {props.user.employees.length === 0 )? ....}
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

No sé cómo acceder al array. Si en las props paso el array directamente funciona bien.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puede que en el render inicial todavia no se haya definido el user. Te sugiero primero validar que el user existe antes de intentar acceder a el. Ejemplo:

```
<tr>
  {props.user && props.user.employees.length === 0 ? .... : .... }
</tr>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, validando el user funciona